# tornado file upload is blocking

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I am trying to create a file upload service with Tornado.

But I noticed that when multiple users uploads files, tornado waits for the first in to finish and process the next one.

What is the proper way of doing ASYNC file uploads on Tornado?

My post:

```
  @tornado.web.asynchronous
  def post(self):
    list_of_img = ['png','jpg','jpeg','gif']
    list_of_files = ['rtf','txt','ppt','pptx','doc','docx','pdf','xls','xlsx','rar','zip','tgz','bz','gz','tar','bz2','3gp','mp4','m15','avi','mp3']
    path  =  __UPLOADS__
    try:
      fileinfo = self.request.files['file'][0]
      filebody = fileinfo['body']
      filename = fileinfo['filename']
      filetype = fileinfo['content_type']
      extn     = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]

      n_filename = str(uuid.uuid4()) + extn

      # rcv file
      print "saving", n_filename + "..."
      output_file = open(n_filename, 'w')
      output_file.write(filebody)

      # upload to s3
      print "uploading", n_filename + "..."

      self.upload(path, n_filename)

      # clean up
      print "cleaning", n_filename + "..."
      self.delete_local(n_filename)

      self.finish(n_filename)
    except KeyError, key:
      delete = self.get_argument("delete", None, True)
      if delete:
        filename = self.get_argument("filename", None, True)

        print "deleting", filename + "..."
        self.delete(path, filename)

        self.finish(filename)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@asynchronous` decorator should be used to mark a method that is already asynchronous; it does not *make* the method asynchronous.  This `post` method is synchronous because it does everything it is going to do before returning control to the IOLoop.  You need to make the `upload()` method asynchronous (which generally means it will either take a callback argument or return a `Future`) and then call it without blocking from `post()` (I recommend using the `@gen.coroutine` decorator and calling slow operations by yielding the `Futures` they return).

Comment: That's a big question.  You have to identify all the blocking parts of the system and replace them with non-blocking equivalents.  This generally means you can't use any networking libraries except those designed to be used asynchronously.  There is no free lunch here; the change to the interface is what it means to be asynchronous.

Comment: seriously. This is common problem, and unable to find a best approach to handle async file-upload. BTW, its good to find few issues before writing my complete app on tornado.

Answer (score 0):

Gevent (Greenlets) are free-lunch way to address BLocking parts.

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```

But careful , sometime it breaks things.